# How to access call logs in android using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to access recent call logs using Cordova but there is no official plugin for that, some guy made a custom plugin for that https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin is the only hope for me, but the problem is this plugin is no longer supported by its creator and it is using AngularJS in his example. I did my search work and found that People tried to use this plugin to use with javascript but they got no working solution. As the author mentioned here https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin/issues/4 there are 3 functions that will work with javascript.

```
window.plugins.calllog.list : get recent calls - takes a day limit e.g 7 is go back a week
window.plugins.calllog.show : show contact for specified phone number
window.plugins.calllog.contact : get contact details for specified phone number
```

I tried each of them and **apparently window.plugins.calllog.show is working fine** and it is showing contact for specific numbers. But **window.plugins.calllog.list** did not worked for me it is returning "undefined". Need help please. Thanks in advance.

my **index.html** contains

```
<button id="call_log" onclick="loadLogs();">call log</button>
```

my **app.js** contains

```
    //calllog
    function loadLogs() {

        if(window.plugins.calllog == "undefined"){
               alert("Doesn't works");
           }
        else
           {
                alert("works");
                window.plugins.calllog.show('12345'); 
                //this code is working and opening list of contacts having these "12345" in their phonenumber

                var list = window.plugins.calllog.list('7');
                alert(list[0]);
            }

    }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Paste here your code, so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Do you inject `CallLogService` in your controller? Looking example in Github plugin page you should do: 
`CallLogService.list(1).then(
            function(callLog) {
                console.log(callLog);
                $scope.data.lastCall = callLog[0];
            },
            function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });`

Comment: `window.plugins.calllog.list(days, function (response) {
               // Do something with response;
            }, function (error) {
               // Damn got an error. useful print it
            });`
As you can see you should pass a function in case of success and a function in case of error. Or you can use the CallLogService, injecting it in your controller

Comment: This works thank you so much. I have wasted more than 24 hours for a working solution and now you saved my life.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get call log history using Cordova CallLog plugin for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809391/how-get-call-log-history-using-cordova-calllog-plugin-for-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a plugin I have made

https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsplugin

you basically have to write the command

```
cordova plugin add callsplugin
```

and follow the instruction you find in the project site

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have recently noticed some related issues on the GitHub repository. I think I should update the project to the possible changes in the OS and libraries. Could you pleas add an issue with your device configuration (i.e. OS version). I will try to work on it this week.

Comment: I have updated the README explaining  how to correctly add the app permissions required to avoid the security exception. Basically your app needs to be authorized to read the User Log.

Comment: thanks for your support. i have already granted permission using another npm package.